# Is there a way to handle proc that does not exist in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl. Is there a way we can handle the procs that does not exist though being called in the script. I am giving you the example

Suppose this is our code

```
package require 65ABC
package provide package1
65ABC::callingFunction param1 param2  (# this does not exist in 65ABC)

It will throw an error saying undefined command 65ABC::callingFunction
```

If i remember correctly not sure about `TCL` but in other languages, in these cases there is a `universal proc`. It means in the above mentioned scenarios when the calling function does not exist, it will go to some universal proc and does what is written inside universal proc. Say we can print a message saying "this proc does not exist" or we can do some other operations.

**Update:** adding `catch` command is not a option. As i am around 200 such procs. I want to handle these scenarios by one superproc

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is the `unknown` and/or `namespace unknown` command. These commands are documented here:

- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/unknown.htm
- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M22

Here's a quick example of `unknown`:

```tcl
% rename unknown _unknown ;# save reference to the original
% proc unknown {args} {
    puts stderr "Hey, I don't know this command: $args"
    uplevel 1 [list _unknown {*}$args]
}
% hello world
Hey, I don't know this command: hello world
invalid command name "hello"
```

You can, of course, do anything you want inside this proc -- you can log information, dynamically create missing procs, raise an error, and so on.

Comment: Where we need to write unknown proc. Can we write in the package 65ABC. 65ABC is the package where we are searching for proc say 65ABC::testProc

Comment: Instead of writing unknown proc in script, can i write this in the package with namespace attached say `65ABC::unknown`. I need that kind of solution

Comment: `namespace unknown` is not working. If i am writing `proc unknown` it is working. Now the problem is it is modifying each error and calling `unknown` proc. Suppose if something is wrong in the code it is directly going to `unknown` proc and masking the error

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`catch`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/catch.htm):

```
package require 65ABC
package provide package1
if {[catch {65ABC::callingFunction param1 param2} err]} {
    puts "Error: $err"
}
```

Or maybe [`try`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm)...`on error`:

```
package require 65ABC
package provide package1

try {
    65ABC::callingFunction param1 param2
} on error {result options} {
    puts "Something's not so right..."
    return -options $options $result
}
```

Comment: @Nitesh What do you mean?

Comment: Problem is I am having around 200 such procs. I can't put catch for each proc. If i get something like universal proc then i need to add the message once only

Comment: Have you got what I am trying to say. or should i explain in much detail?

Comment: You know universal means if the TCL does not find an proc that is called in the proc then it will redirect to universal proc

Comment: @Nitesh It's not advisable, but you could as well wrap everything in a single `catch`. It's like you're `source`-ing from a script and wrapping the `source`: `if {[catch {source scripts.tcl} err]} {...}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems the original poster (OP) is interested in handling only unknown procedures in the name space `65ABC`. If this is the case, then the `proc unknown` must be more selective: it has to figure out which name space the unknown proc belongs to. If it is `65ABC`, then we will handle it ourselves. Otherwise, we will let the system handle it. Here is what I have in mind:

```
rename unknown original_unknown; # Save the original unknown 
proc getns {name {defaultNS "::"}} {
    set lastSeparatorPosition [string last "::" $name]
    if {$lastSeparatorPosition == -1} {
        return $defaultNS
    } else {
        incr lastSeparatorPosition -1
        return [string range $name 0 $lastSeparatorPosition]
    }
}   
proc unknown {args} {
    set procName [lindex $args 0]
    set ns [getns $procName]
    puts "$args, happens in name space -- $ns"

    if {$ns == "::65ABC" || $ns == "65ABC"} {
        puts "  We will handle this ourselves"
    } else {
        uplevel 1 [list original_unknown {*}$args]
    }
}

# Test it out
namespace eval ::65ABC {
    proc foo {args} { puts "::65ABC::foo $args" }

    # This will never get called
    proc unknown {args} {
        puts "::65ABC::unknown -- $args"
    }
}

::65ABC::bar hello there; # We will handle this case
65ABC::foobar 1 2 3;      # Also handle this case
foo bar;                  # The system will handle this case
```

## Output

```
::65ABC::bar hello there, happens in name space -- ::65ABC
  We will handle this ourselves
65ABC::foobar 1 2 3, happens in name space -- 65ABC
  We will handle this ourselves
foo bar, happens in name space -- ::
invalid command name "foo"
    while executing
"original_unknown foo bar"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 [list original_unknown {*}$args]"
    (procedure "::unknown" line 12)
    invoked from within
"foo bar"
    (file "/Users/haiv/Dropbox/src/tcl/unknown_proc.tcl" line 47)
```

## Discussion

- The `proc unknown` I have is essentially the same as Bryan Oakley's, but with some extra code to determine what name space the unknown proc belongs to.
- To determine the unknown proc's name space, I created `proc gents`, which returns the text before the last `"::"`. If the proc name does not contain `"::"`, then `gents` will returns `"::"` for the global name space.
- Writing the `unknown` proc within the namespace `65ABC` does not work. I have tried it.

Comment: `getns` can be replaced by the builtin `namespace qualifiers` command

Answer (score 0):

This is just an expansion of Bryan Oakley's answer.  You can use tcl's introspection to see the caller and take the appropriate action.  Any calls not originating in the B:: namespace will be processed as usual.

```
rename unknown _unknown
proc unknown {args} {
  array set i [info frame 1]
  # if the uknown command is in the B:: namespace, use our own
  # handler, otherwise, run the default.
  if { [regexp {^B::} $i(cmd)] } {
    puts "unk: $args"
  } else {
    uplevel 1 [list _unknown {*}$args]
  }
}

namespace eval B {
  proc x {} {
    puts "B::x"
  }
}

B::x
B::y
xyzzy
```